# How to find all matches in a string with a regex in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I have a string (html) and trying to find information by pattern;
For example:

```
<div>
  <include name="component">
</div>

<div>
  <include name="position">
</div>
```

And I would like to get an

```
array(
  [0]=>component,
  [1]=>position
);
```

I have tried:

```
$pattern = '/<include name="(.*?)".*?>/';
preg_match($pattern, $template, $matches);
```

But it's not working right;
Thanks!

Comment: What are you getting that is not working right when you run your code, can you post any errors please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex is correct but it get only the first match. To overcome this, you have to use `preg_match_all` function